# How much storage does Nier take on ps3?

Tags: nier

So I'm thinking about buying Nier for my ps3. How much storage does it take up?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer NieR is a different game. Automata is ps4 and PC only, so OP is definitely talking about the former.

Comment: This does not need the PS3 tag as it's about the game specifically, not the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/960449-nier/54465807), the install size is just 4GB, but it's *optional*.

After going home, I checked my own NIER disc and it appears that the amount of *required* HDD space is 7111KB, so less than 1GB.

[image: NIER storage requirements]

According to the [PS Store listing for NIER](https://store.playstation.com/#!/en-us/games/nier/cid=UP0082-BLUS30481_00-NIER000000000000?scope=sceapp&smcid=sceapp&psappver=4.20.9:home), this game is disc-only, so digital download is not an option. 7111KB is all that you need, with an extra 4GB being optional.

---

From experience, though, you should have 20% or so of your HDD free if you want your games to run well. Running games when you have extremely little storage remaining causes games to perform very poorly.

Comment: thank you for the answer i tried going on the ps store and it didn't say how much it needed.

Comment: @captaincj2005 yeah the PS store wouldn't give a number if its disc only, unfortunately